# Anywhere to download Wine for Xubuntu?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, wine, internet

I am completely new to the Linux world and am already having troubles. I installed Xubuntu on an old desktop and am trying to set up a USB wifi adapter to get some internet connection on the thing. I need Wine to run the setup software for the adapter, but it seems the only way to get it is to have an internet connection! I'm stuck and can't make any sense of the limited information I have found by searching the internet so far. Would it be easier to just install a different OS that comes with Wine already? Your help and patience with me is much appreciated!!

Info from lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with wine, it's just not one of the packages that's installed by default.  You use the software centre to install it ([here is a link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine/)).

Ubuntu has come with Wine 1.4 since 12.04 and before that had Wine 1.2, but Ubuntu 14.04 is set to include Wine 1.6.

Xubuntu is just Ubuntu with a different set of packages installed by default which modify the default desktop environment and boot screens. You still can install the same software on it.

> I need Wine to run the setup software for the adapter,

No, you don't.  You don't install Windows drivers on Linux.

Does the adapter not just work when you plug it in?  Ubuntu has a lot of drivers for hardware included already, and can support more by installing certain other packages.

If not, start a new question asking for how to install your wifi adapter, and mention the model number of the adapter, what you've tried and any specific error messages or problems.  Make sure you search first to see if the question is already answered though.

Comment: neon, no it doesn't do anything when I plug it in. I found an ethernet cable and am connected to the internet that way temporarily. I'm doing recommended updates right now to see if that will change anything, and then will search for the specific usb adapter. It is a Netgear N300 wifi usb adapter.